# Ошибка при компиляции 'EnterColsAndRows' doesn't contain a definition for 'EnterColsAndRows_Load'

Tags: c#, winforms

```
  public partial class EnterWidthAndHeight : Form
    {
        public EnterWidthAndHeight()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public int width_of_nonogram;
        public int height_of_nonogram;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             width_of_nonogram = int.Parse(WidthOfNonogram.ToString());
             height_of_nonogram = int.Parse(HeightOfNonogram.ToString());
            EnterColsAndRows enterColsAndRows = new EnterColsAndRows(width_of_nonogram,height_of_nonogram);
            enterColsAndRows.Show();

        }

    }
}





 public partial class EnterColsAndRows : Form
    {
        private int width_of_nonogram;
        private int height_of_nonogram;
        public EnterColsAndRows(int width,int height)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            width_of_nonogram = width;
            height_of_nonogram = height;

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы скорей всего кликнули два раза по форме, что привело к подписке на событие OnLoad и создало метод, по типу следующего:

```
private void EnterColsAndRows_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /****/
}
```

Который вы благополучно в дальнейшем удалили из кода.

Выход:

1. Можете создать метод заного (код выше).
2. Можете отписаться:

   - Либо удалив из файла `EnterColsAndRows.Designer.cs` строку, которая отвечает за подпись на данное событие (она у вас отображаться красной, как ошибка). Сама строчка выглядит так: `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.EnterColsAndRows_Load);`
   - Либо зайти в конструктор формы, там будет окно с ошибкой, а в верхнем правом углу ссылка "Перейти к коду". Жмете и удаляете строку.